# Present TTTabbar Vertically

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, three20

I want to create a TTTabbar that will presented Vertically and not horizontally as the default one.

I tried so far to rotate the TTTabbar with cgaffinetransformmakerotation but no luck there.
when i'm rotating it stretch.

any suggestions?
:)

**[EDIT]**

I had to add the TTtabbar to a uiview, otherwise the tttabbar stretches all over the screen

```
this.rightView = new UIView();
this.rightView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.ScrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor;
RectangleF applicationFrame = UIScreen.MainScreen.ApplicationFrame;

//applicationFrame.Y -=20;

TTTabBar ttTabBar = new TTTabBar(new RectangleF(0,0,applicationFrame.Height,40));
ttTabBar.TabItems = NSArray.FromNSObjects(new TTTabItem("one"),new TTTabItem("two"),new TTTabItem("three"));

rightView.Frame = new RectangleF(110,applicationFrame.Height/2,applicationFrame.Height,40);

this.rightView.AddSubview(ttTabBar);
rightView.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation((float)(Math.PI*90)/180);
```

Comment: How exactly did you try to rotate it? Please show your code. And what do you mean with "no luck"? Did you receive an error? Did the app crash?

Comment: How exactly did you try to rotate it? Please show your code. And what do you mean by "it stretches". If you what help, please give info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, looks like TTTabBar really doesn't like to be rotated like this. This is because of it's internal implementation. The easiest workaround would be to rotate the parent view. If that is not possible in your case, wrap a new view around the tabBar and rotate that one.